# Creating a chat application from scratch

Tags: android

I want to create a chat application from scratch, I don't want to use anyone else's code.

What should I use to send the text back and forth? I've tried a java socket, but there is something missing.

Should I go that route or is there something else out there?

Comment: Not using other people's code is very short sighted. Everything you're doing you're using other people's code in some way or another. If you're using the android SDK or NDK you're using someone else's code, if you're using any frameworks then you're using someone else's code. Some things just aren't worth learning yet. Creating an XMPP chat client from scratch is one of those things. No point reinventing the wheel. If you need to build on top of something else then do that.

Comment: well that came out wrong, I dont want to use a program created by somebody else. I always do my own programming.

Comment: right yeah, of course. But using a framework/library by someone else is fine.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very broad question and will probably get closed soon.

What you need is a protocol called XMPP. Its basically like push notifications, the protocol allows you to PUSH messages down a maintained open/persistent connection. It is also known as a comet connection.

Its quite complicated, so it would be worth looking into creating your own jabber protocol first. Here is a useful framework (found using a google search) http://code.google.com/p/jabberoid/ which might help you. You may be able to use the framework to create your own private jabber service which can be used to power your chat client.

Hope this helps, look out for XMPP information, and a server called Openfire. XMPP is the protocol (extensible messaging and presence protocol) you will need to use (like you would use http or ftp) and Openfire is a free, opensource XMPP/Jabber client server software (just like you would use apache or mysql).

Hope that helps as a start point for you.

Comment: +1 and also another grate project http://beem-project.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. I used to do a lot of integration so Im used to the hard and complicated stuff. but finally the answer I was looking for, thanks again....:)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. If its the right answer then feel free to click the green tick mark on the left to mark as your accepted answer.